# how to avoid standalone pages occur in arxiv upload

Tags: standalone, arxiv

In my paper's main tex file I included many standalone tex files and when I upload all the tex file to arxiv, arxiv generated all the standalone pages before rendering my main tex file, is there a way to avoid this? something like telling latex2e not to process the standalone file but only my main.tex file?

Comment: When uploading to arXiv there is the possibility to choose which file is the main file. But I fear this is off-topic here.

Comment: @campa, I am not sure if there is such option on arxiv? Since I did not find that yet?

Comment: @campa, actually, i tried using 00README.XXX in arxiv upload to specify the main file, but still, only standalone pdf are generated